# How to check data selected using LOG:INFO Laravel

Tags: laravel, debugging

How I can check the selected elements that I pass from front end using Log::info? I tried using this but I dont know how to check the result, or maybe the code is wrong?

```
public function filterQuery(Request $request){

    $name= $request->name;
    $age= $request->age;

    Log::info('Showing user profile for user: '.$name);

    $query = user::query();

   if(!empty($request->name)){
        $query->where('name',$name);
    }
```